# printf values inside single bracket

Tags: c

I was just practicing with beginner code printing odds and evens and I could never figure out how to print them inside a simple for loop such that the values stay inside 1 single bracket { } like this:

```
The·even·number·in·range·are·{2,·4,·6,·8,·10}.
```

And not like this:

```
The even number in range are {2} The even number in range are {4}
```

Edit: oops forgot to place code fragment.

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
    r=i%2;
    if(r==0){
      printf("The even number in range are {%d} ",i);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you printing the message inside the `for` if you only want it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n=21;
    printf("The even number in range are {");
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
        (i%2)? 0:printf("%d ", i);
    }
    printf("}\n");
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5436KB
The even number in range are {2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 }
```

Comment: Why even bother with the test? Just loop `for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2) { ... }`